# React Native Authentication with Firebase Throws an Error

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am writing an authentication system for my Expo app and I am using firebase, however after icluding all the code correctly, it throws an error saying:

> TypeError: 0, _auth2.signInWithPopup is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes`

I tried this code which is linked to a button in the app:

```
const handleGoogleSignIn = () => {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then((result) => {
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
        const token = credential.accessToken;
        // The signed-in user info.
        const user = result.user;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle Errors here.
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        // The email of the user's account used.
        const email = error.customData.email;
        // The AuthCredential type that was used.
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
        // ...
      });
  };
```

I expected that whenever the button is clicked on my Expo Go App, a Google Signup Window would appear. However, an error is thrown `TypeError: 0, _auth2.signInWithPopup is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes`

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71026130/react-native-google-authentication-not-working-typeerror-0-auth-signinwith? This also seems quite relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75346287/using-firebase-google-authentication-with-react-native